# Combined Select Statement

Tags: database, lua

I need to select from a database several values with different combinations possibilities for checking an event and do the correct action to each:

Example Event: "Man wears a 1930 green Italian hat."

Need to get all values in a database like this:

object -- color -- country -- year

```
hat    -- any   -- any     -- any
hat    -- green -- any     -- any
hat    -- green -- Italian -- any
(...)    
hat    -- any   -- Italian -- any
hat    -- any   -- Italian -- 1930
```

In a way I can check the actions bound to:

```
Wearing a green, Italian, 1930 hat
Wearing a green, hat
Wearing a hat
(And so on for all the possibilities that exists)
```

This way I could start all the procedures for a man wearing a hat and the specific procedures for a man wearing a green italian hat, for example.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of database are you talking about?
Is this a SQL database?
Do you have a table for colors, one for countries, ... ?
What exactly are you trying to do? Create values from that example event or create all possible events from the values?

Since you tagged this with Lua, I assume those "properties" are in tables as in:

```
local colors = {"green","red"}
local countries = {"Italian","Mexican"}
local years = {1930,2016}
```

I'm guessing you want to create all possible events from those properties:

```
for _,color in pairs(colors) do
    for _,country in pairs(countries) do
        for _,year in pairs(years) do
            print("Wearing a "..table.concat({color,country,year},", ").." hat")
        end
    end
end
```

You can run this code on the Lua demo page: http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

The result is that every possible combination is outputted. The only thing that might not be right is the implementation of your "any".

If you want to have combinations with no color/country/hat, you could add "" to the lists. It would probably be better to use a numeric for loop and adding an extra iteration, as in:

```
for i=1,#colors+1 do
    --etc
end
```